# Two disassembly windows in IDA

Tags: ida

Is there any way I can have a kind of "split-view" where I can look at the disassembly of two different portions of the code(of a single file) in IDA? It'd be nice to be able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can open multiple disassembly [MDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface) windows by going to `View → Open subviews → Disassembly` in IDA's menubar. For example, if you already have a disassembly window open and open a new disassembly subview, your original disassembly window tab will be named `IDA View-A` and your new disassembly window tab will be named `IDA View-B`. You can then rearrange the disassembly windows (drag and drop the window tabs) to create a split-view.